# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fileprovider

I am trying to use ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent to capture an image and then save it to /data/data/**/app_profile/profile_picture.jpg
I call the intent with the following code:

```
val cw = ContextWrapper(this@UserActivity.applicationContext)
val dir:File = cw.getDir("profile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

output = File(dir, "/profile_picture.jpg")
intent = Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

**val newPhotoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(applicationContext, "$packageName.fileprovider", output)**

intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, newPhotoUri)
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA)

Log.e(TAG, "output: ${output.absolutePath}") ///data/user/0/**/app_profile/profile_picture.jpg
```

But I get the following crash on `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/**/app_profile/profile_picture.jpg
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:739)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:418)
    at **.UserActivity.takePhoto(UserActivity.kt:147)
```

I have the following set in Manifest:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="**.fileprovider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
</provider>
```

My filepaths.xml:

```
<paths>
    <files-path name="app_profile" path="." />
</paths>
```

I have already tried

```
<files-path name="app_profile" path="app_profile/" />
```

and a lot of other combinations.
Can someone guide me through?

Comment: I fixed it myself. Instead of doing val dir:File = cw.getDir("profile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself. Instead of doing

```
val dir:File = cw.getDir("profile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

I had to do

```
val dir:File = cw.filesDir
```

Which returns the correct /files/ directory.
Now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the source of `FileProvider`, and found an undocumented solution:

`<root-path name="root_files" path="." />`

This will apparently grant access to every dir your app can access. Probably not the safest (especially if you already have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`), but it *will* let you share files located under `context.getDir()`, which is otherwise impossible.

Probably the better solution tho is to copy or move your files under `context.getFilesDir()`, if you can.